# Cannot set the time on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

I have a problem setting the system time on a Debian 7.4 Wheezy machine. The machine is a VirtualBox guest VM. I did the following:

`/etc/init.d/ntp stop
date -s 2014-05-01`

After these commands, the time is updated, but changes back to real time after a few seconds. I thought, that disabling NTP should do the trick. In fact, it did in the past. But this time it seems something else is manipulating my system clock automatically. I'm kind of lost here. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the /var/log/daemon and messages files, check your running processes and check your /etc/crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VirtualBox Issue. Automatic setting of the system time can be deactivated on the host via:

```
vboxmanage setextradata <vmname> “VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled” “1″
```

See: http://rickguyer.com/virtualbox-disable-time-sync-between-host-and-client/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`